Template file in Next.js 14 vs browser's back button
I am encountering an issue with implementing page transitions in Next.js 14 using a template.tsx file.I want to create smooth transitions between pages. While the transitions work correctly when navigating normally, they don't function as expected when using the browser's back button. Specifically, when I press the back button, the transition animation doesn't play, and the page is stuck with a blue background, as if the animation is not being triggered.
Template.tsx
"use client";
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { animatePageIn } from "./lib/pageTransition";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

export default function Template({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const pathname = usePathname();

  useEffect(() => {
      animatePageIn();
  }, [pathname]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        id="banner-1"
        className="min-h-screen bg-[#219ebc] z-50 fixed top-0 left-0 w-0 md:w-1/4"
      />
      <div
        id="banner-2"
        className="min-h-screen bg-[#219ebc] z-50 fixed top-0 left-1/4 w-0 md:w-1/4"
      />
      <div
        id="banner-3"
        className="min-h-screen bg-[#219ebc] z-50 fixed top-0 left-2/4 w-0 md:w-1/4"
      />
      <div
        id="banner-4"
        className="min-h-screen bg-[#219ebc] z-50 fixed top-0 left-3/4 w-0 md:w-1/4"
      />
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

pageTransition.ts
import gsap from "gsap"

export const animatePageIn = () => {
  const bannerOne = document.getElementById("banner-1")
  const bannerTwo = document.getElementById("banner-2")
  const bannerThree = document.getElementById("banner-3")
  const bannerFour = document.getElementById("banner-4")

  if (bannerOne && bannerTwo && bannerThree && bannerFour) {
    const tl = gsap.timeline()

    tl.set([bannerFour, bannerThree, bannerTwo, bannerOne], {
      yPercent: 0,
    }).to([bannerFour, bannerThree, bannerTwo, bannerOne], {
      yPercent: 100,
      stagger: 0.5,
      duration:1.5,

    })
  }
}

I've tried to use POP state listener to track to manually detect when the browser's back button was pressed - unfortunately it didn't work as intended. I've put the popstate listener in useEffect hook inside Template.tsx. Moreover I've tried to detect pathname using usePathname but it also failed.
Summing up, I want to have a clear transition with animation triggering every time no matter if I pressed back button, Link component or Button. The problem seems to occur sometimes, not every time that's why it's hard for me to track when exactly (I've tested that problem on Safari, Chrome, Opera). I suppose it might be related to some cashing that browsers do (I might be totally wrong on that one).
